# Opsworks with Chef 12 can't access deploy ssh_key

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-solo, aws-opsworks, databags

Per the [OpsWorks documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html) with Chef v11 or earlier you could access a deploy key by doing:

```
include 'deploy'
key = node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:scm][:ssh_key]
```

However per [OpsWorks with Chef 12](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-to-data-bags.html) documentation:

> To migrate your recipe code that accesses stack settings from Chef
>   11.10 and earlier versions for Linux to Chef 12 Linux, you must revise your code to:
>
> - Access Chef data bags instead of Chef attributes.
> - Use Chef search instead of the Chef node object.
> - Use AWS OpsWorks data bag names such as aws_opsworks_app, instead of using AWS * OpsWorks attribute names such as opsworks and deploy.

My issue is that the documentation on how to access the ssh_key for deploy hasn't been updated to show where in the databags I can find the key.

Does anyone know of up-to-date documentation or can someone point me in the right direction for locating the ssh deploy key?

Answer (score 2):

This is listed in this documentation page, under 'app_source': http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-app.html#data-bag-json-app-app-source

Here is a slightly changed example from the above page which also shows SSH key:

```
search("aws_opsworks_app").each do |app|
  Chef::Log.info("********** The app's short name is '#{app['shortname']}' **********")
  Chef::Log.info("********** The app's ssh_key is '#{app['app_source’][‘ssh_key’]}’ **********")
end
```